# Bound on $x$ for $x-\ln x\ge 1+\epsilon$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, closed-form

I'm looking for a function $x(\cdot)$ where the domain is $\mathbb{R}^+$, that satisfies the following:

1. For all $\epsilon > 0$, the inequality $x-\ln x\ge 1+\epsilon$ is satisfied for all $x \geq x(\epsilon)$, and
2. For all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+$, the value of $x(\epsilon)$ is close to being as small as possible while still satisfying 1. above.

For example, for all $\epsilon > 0$, the inequality $x-\ln x\ge 1+\epsilon$ clearly is satisfied for all $x \geq 100+100\epsilon$. But given any such $\epsilon$, as $x$ can still satisfy the inequality $x-\ln x\ge 1+\epsilon$ and be much smaller than 
$100+100\epsilon$, the function $100+100\epsilon$ is not what would suffice here for $x(\epsilon)$.

Furthermore, for such an $x(\epsilon)$ I need a close-form expression.

I've tried playing with iteratively setting $x\ge\ln x + 1+\epsilon$, but I don't see it leading anywhere:
$x\ge\ln x+ 1+\epsilon\ge\ln (\ln x+ 1+\epsilon)+ 1+\epsilon\ge\ln (\ldots (\ln x+ 1+\epsilon)\ldots+ 1+\epsilon)+ 1+\epsilon$.

Intuitively, it should suffice that $x$ will be *slightly* larger than $1+\epsilon$, but I'm struggling to get a reasonable value for it.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: Playing a bit with Wolfram Alpha, I saw that setting $x(\epsilon)=1.6(1+\epsilon)$ also works. This is not ideal as I hope for a bound that tends to $1$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

EDIT2: It seems that $x(\epsilon)=1+\epsilon+\sqrt {2\epsilon}$ also works. I don't have any intuition as to why this works or if there's an easy way of proving it.

In contrast, it seems that $1+c\cdot \epsilon$ doesn't work for *any* $c\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Have you tried expanding $\log(x)$ as a taylor series?

Comment: Yes, I get something that $x^2/2-x^3/3\ge 1+\epsilon$ is enough, but I'm not clear on how to extract a good bound from it.

Comment: It seems you want a *lower* bound $x(\epsilon)$, not an upper bound.

Comment: Thanks Prof. @ChristianBlatter for your comment. Mike did a good job explaining what I'm looking for in his edit; I think you're right that it should be called a lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

First, we observe that
$$
f(x)=x-\ln x -1\geq \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}-\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}=g(x).
$$
Now clearly if 
$$
g(x)\geq\varepsilon \Rightarrow f(x)\geq \varepsilon
$$

Now all we have to do is to find the roots $f(x)-\varepsilon=0$ and identify the one which is larger than, but close to $1$.
It is given by
$$
x(\varepsilon)=-\frac{1}{4}(1-12\varepsilon+2\sqrt{36\varepsilon^2-6\varepsilon})^\tfrac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4(1-12\varepsilon+2\sqrt{36\varepsilon^2-6\varepsilon})^\tfrac{1}{3}}+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(\frac{1-12\varepsilon+2\sqrt{36\varepsilon^2-6\varepsilon})^\tfrac{1}{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2(1-12\varepsilon+2\sqrt{36\varepsilon^2-6\varepsilon})^\tfrac{1}{3})}\right)
$$

edit: If this expression does not satisfy you, you can of, of course expand it around $\varepsilon=0$ to get:

$$
x(\varepsilon)\approx 1+\sqrt{2\varepsilon}+\tfrac{2}{3}\varepsilon+\tfrac{5}{9}\sqrt{2}\varepsilon^\tfrac{3}{2}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not clear why you'd have imaginary part to your solution, and how to "round up" the $\epsilon=0$ expansion to get a correct bound.
Also, I'm not sure if (or, for what range of $\epsilon$) this gives a better bound than the $1+\epsilon+3\sqrt{\epsilon}$ (which can be tightened a bit to $1+\epsilon+\sqrt{2 \epsilon}$) I propose in the question.

Comment: You do not get an imaginary part. (At least for small $\varepsilon$) The imaginary unit is just there from the formula for polynomials of third degree and will cancel out. If you want to compare the bounds, or determine where to stop in an expansion i recommend simply plotting it.

Answer (score 0):

$x(\epsilon)=x-\ln(x)-1$ is the largest upper bound possible, and also happens to be in closed form.

Comment: I'm probably not explaining myself correctly. $x(\epsilon)$ should only be a function of $\epsilon$. E.g., $x(\epsilon) = 100+100\epsilon$ works, but is a *very* loose bound.